# php add new set of element in in multidimentional array in no value is present in one dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my result array

```
$resultVal = Array
 (  
    [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                (
                        [crate] => 13.51
                        [ucount] => 36
                        [udate] => 2016-06-30
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                        [crate] => 20.51
                        [ucount] => 36
                        [udate] => 2016-07-30
                )
         )
    )
```

and below is my month array

```
$MonthArray =array("June 2016","July 2016","August 2016");
```

And my expected array is below,

```
$expectedArray = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [crate] => 13.51
                    [ucount] => 36
                    [udate] => June 2016
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [crate] => 0
                    [ucount] => 0
                    [udate] => July 2016
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [crate] => 0
                    [ucount] => 0
                    [udate] => Aug 2016
                )
        )
```

I have to display expected array on basis of month array.

No value is present in month of July 2016, so I have to add full set of elemenst.

I am using `array_combine()` and `in_array()` to set count `0` if no date for particular month.

But for adding element is only set for one element not for both elements.

Please suggest a best solution.

Comment: How I understood question you need 1 array for each month right? Or if not, can you please explain a little bit better what you expect.

Comment: so you also need to flatten the array by one level?

Comment: I am creating array on basis of month.Suppose I have 4 month(Jan,Feb,march,April) in month array and in result array having only 2 indexes for Jan and march but I want same elements for March and April also.So I can plot a chart for four month.I also give expectedArray which  want.

Comment: I want array like this,  $expectedArray = Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [crate] => 13.51
                        [ucount] => 36
                        [udate] => June 2016
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [crate] => 0
                        [ucount] => 0
                        [udate] => July 2016
                    )
            )  add element set for month that month is not present in result array.

Comment: Can you add one more element in `$resultVal` so that we will understand the structure of array .

Comment: Another element added in `$resultVal[1]` is it right ?

Comment: yes is basis on month if 4 moth I want 4 element in expected array with zero values

Comment: my code,$final_array = array_combine ( $MonthArray, array_fill ( 0, count ( $MonthArray ), 0 ) );
foreach ( $new_array as $item ) {$month = $item ['udate'];if (in_array ( $month, $MonthArray )) {$final_array [$month] += $item ['crate'];}}
$i = 0;$finalArray = array ();foreach ( $final_array as $key => $value ) {$finalArray [$i] ['crate'] = "$value";$finalArray [$i] ['udate'] = date ( "M jS Y", strtotime ( $key ) );$i ++;}

Comment: I am getting crate only I want ucount also in array

Comment: Your question contradicts itself.  `$resultVal` contains data for July 30th, but you later say "No value is present in month of July 2016".  Please clarify your question because your question doesn't make sense and the accepted answer adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to loop the month array like below .

```
<?php

$resultVal = Array ("0" => Array("0" => Array("crate" => 13.51,"ucount" => 36,"udate" => '2016-06-30')));

$MonthArray =array("June 2016","July 2016");

$formated_column = array_map(function($v){ return date('F Y',strtotime($v['udate'])); },$resultVal[0]);

//here using array_map to build a formated udate array column .

$new_array =array();

for($i=0;$i<count($MonthArray);$i++){ //here looping month column

    $exists_array_key = array_search($MonthArray[$i],$formated_column);
      //here searching the month value exists in formated array or not .
    if($exists_array_key !==false){

        $resultVal[0][$exists_array_key]['udate']=date('F Y',strtotime($resultVal[0][$exists_array_key]['udate']));

        $new_array[]=  $resultVal[0][$exists_array_key];

    }else{

        $new_array[]= Array("crate" =>"","ucount" =>"","udate" =>$MonthArray[$i] );
    }

}

print_r($new_array );


?>
```

OUT PUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [crate] => 13.51
            [ucount] => 36
            [udate] => June 2016
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [crate] =>
            [ucount] =>
            [udate] => June 2016
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fill an array of defaults (zero'ed out rows) using your `$month` array.  Then prepare your `$results` array in a loop so that its data conforms to the correct format.  Only overwrite the `$defaults` row with the `$results` row.  If the `$results` row didn't exist in `$defaults`, then assume it shouldn't be in the output.

When finished iterating, call `array_values()` to re-index the output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/g10oT))

```
$months = ['June 2016', 'July 2016', 'August 2016'];
$results = [
    [
        ['crate' => 13.51, 'ucount' => 36, 'udate' => '2016-06-30'],
        ['crate' => 20.51, 'ucount' => 36, 'udate' => '2016-07-30']
    ]
];

$defaults = [];
foreach ($months as $month) {
    $defaults[$month] = ['crate' => 0, 'ucount' => 0, 'udate' => $month];
}

foreach ($results[0] as $row) {
    $formatted = date('F Y', strtotime($row['udate']));  // generate date in desired format
    if (isset($defaults[$formatted])) {
        $row['udate'] = $formatted;  // overwrite the row value
        $defaults[$formatted] = $row;  // overwrite the default row
    }
}
var_export(array_values($defaults));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'crate' => 13.51,
    'ucount' => 36,
    'udate' => 'June 2016',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'crate' => 20.51,
    'ucount' => 36,
    'udate' => 'July 2016',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'crate' => 0,
    'ucount' => 0,
    'udate' => 'August 2016',
  ),
)
```